Where can I find net-snmp MIB's included on linux
I'm running AlmaLinux 9 (a RedHat 9 clone), and have net-snmp installed.  I thought this would automatically include a generic linux MIB.  But it doesn't and the information online says I should use my package manager (DNF) to download one.
But I can't find one!  Should a MIB have been installed by the package manager when I installed net-snmp?  If not, where can I download a generic Linux MIB?  The only available packages that relate are shown below:
dnf list | grep net-snmp
net-snmp.x86_64                                                                          1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-agent-libs.i686                                                                 1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-agent-libs.x86_64                                                               1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-devel.i686                                                                      1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-devel.x86_64                                                                    1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-libs.i686                                                                       1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-libs.x86_64                                                                     1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-perl.x86_64                                                                     1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
net-snmp-utils.x86_64                                                                    1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        
python3-net-snmp.x86_64                                                                  1:5.9.1-13.el9_4.3                   appstream        


The net-snmp package does not include MIB files by default in AlmaLinux 9
You can install MIB files using the net-snmp-mibs-downloader package
sudo dnf install net-snmp-mibs-downloader
After install the files will located under /usr/share/snmp/mibs/
It looks like AlmaLinux and other Red Hat , does not include MIB files by default with the net-snmp package.
There is no net-snmp-mibs-downloader package available for your current repository, like on Debian-based systems
Try to download manually:

A lot of them only exist in the rfc text. There are some extractor scripts used by various projects.

how/where to download actual ietf mib files 
Simpleweb
Network Services Monitoring MIB
Management Information Base (MIB) for the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) 
ENTITY-SENSOR-MIB
Installing snmp-mibs-downloader on debian 10 buster

There is no such package (I updated the question with DNF output)

The https://github.com/librenms/librenms/tree/master/mibs link shows lots of ready to use MIB's.  But I don't see when for Linux (a generic linux host).  Does such a thing exist?  (Maybe I'm looking for wrong name)

@TSG What would a Linux specific mib give you over what is already there?

I'm just looking for a simple starting point, to which I will add using a subagent.  The collection of MIB's appear to be for routers and other devices.  I just want a MIB for a simple linux host (as the device being monitored).  I read that there is one like that, I just can't see it

@TSG There are host-resources & lm-sensors mibs as standard. Why not just dump the entire tree & have a look around. You will probably find what you need or want is already supplied.

I think I'll investigate this and close the question.  I'll open a related question as you have given me an idea.
